# How do I make django's markdown filter transform a carriage return to <br />?

Tags: python, django, markdown

How can I change the default behavior in the markdown filter so that it transforms a newline to a br tag?

Comment: So, are you trying to say you want markdown to behave differently than it's supposed to?

Markdown is a specific syntax. If you want to invent your own syntax that's fine, but then it's no longer markdown. 

No really sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: @Henrik Joretag - what do you think StackOverflow did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I don't think messing around with the newline syntax is a good idea ...

I agree with Henrik's comment. From the [markdown docs](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax):

> When you do want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.
>
> Yes, this takes a tad more effort to create a `<br />`, but a simplistic “every line break is a `<br />`” rule wouldn’t work for Markdown. Markdown’s email-style blockquoting and multi-paragraph list items work best — and look better — when you format them with hard breaks.

Have you looked at the other Django markup options, textile and restructuredtext? Their syntax might suit you better.

---

### but if you still want to ...

A rough and ready method is to chain the markdown and [linebreaksbr](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) filters.

```
{{ value|markdown|linebreaksbr }}
```

This runs the markdown filter, then the linebreaksbr filter, which replaces `\n` with `<br />`. You'll probably end up with too many linebreaks, but that might be better for you than too few.

If you a better solution than that, you could

1. Write a custom filter, as John suggests in his answer.
2. Dive into the the [python-markdown](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown) library, which Django uses, and [write an extension](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Writing_Extensions) that implements your desired newline syntax. You would then use the extension with the filter

   `{{ value|markdown:"linebreakextension" }}`

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT: As of the end of June, 2011, the extension below is now included with Python Markdown.**

Here is a Markdown extension that I wrote and am currently testing on my site to do exactly what you want:

```
"""
A python-markdown extension to treat newlines as hard breaks; like
StackOverflow and GitHub flavored Markdown do.

"""
import markdown


BR_RE = r'\n'

class Nl2BrExtension(markdown.Extension):

    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        br_tag = markdown.inlinepatterns.SubstituteTagPattern(BR_RE, 'br')
        md.inlinePatterns.add('nl', br_tag, '_end')


def makeExtension(configs=None):
    return Nl2BrExtension(configs)
```

I put this in a file called mdx_nl2br.py and put it on my PYTHONPATH. You can then use it in a Django template like this:

```
{{ value|markdown:"nl2br" }}
```

If you'd like to use it in regular code, you can do something like this:

```
import markdown
md = markdown.Markdown(safe_mode=True, extensions=['nl2br'])
converted_text = md.convert(text)
```

[Here is the starting point in the docs](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Extensions) for using and writing extensions.

Comment: So this is [mentioned in the python-markdown source](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/nl2br) but apparently not shipped in it, or at least not in their latest release?

Comment: @poolie, since I wrote this answer, the Markdown team has now included the extension with Markdown. This was the issue that accepted it: https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/13

Comment: Yep, it's not in the version on pypi (2.0.3), but it is in trunk.  Thanks for adding that!

Comment: @poolie and anyone else. I just learned version 2.1.0 is now on PyPi and it includes this change.

Answer (score 1):

You can override default MARKDOWN_DEUX_STYLES with adding `"break-on-newline": True` in `extras` settings :

```
MARKDOWN_DEUX_STYLES = {
    "default": {
        "extras": {
            "code-friendly": None,
            "break-on-newline": True,
        },
        "safe_mode": "escape",
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/wiki/Extras) of python-markdown2:

> break-on-newline: Replace single new line characters with 
>  when
>   True.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [custom filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that calls markdown, then does [replace](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) on its output.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a `linebreaks` filter that converts `\n` characters to either `<br>` or `<p>`.
See [linebreaks](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) or [linebreaksbr](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr).